# Remove item using its location or key in Firebase React

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a simple react application and I am able to add data to it, but I am not sure how to remove/update data.
the main problem is in getting the part where I tell firebase which data to remove. how do I tell that to firebase.
I am using react.

I have been trying out different things but it's just not working

```
handleRemove(){
  console.log('you reached handleRemove function');
  var ref =firebase.database().ref('items');
  ref.on('value',this.handlegetData,this.handleErrData);
  ['items']['KpAmo20xP6HPXc7cwjY'].remove();
  //itemsRef.remove('KpAmo20xP6HPXc7cwjY');
}
```

Please tell me how to do this.

My firebase database looks somewhat like this
[image]

Comment: Are your keys really starting with a dash/minus character? That's confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need something like that to remove value :

```
handleRemove() {
    return firebase.database().ref('items').child('ITEM_KEY').remove();
}
```

or something like that to update value :

```
handleUpdate() {
    var updates = {};
    updates['/id'] = 1;
    updates['/title'] = 'Apple';

    return firebase.database().ref('items').child('ITEM_KEY').update(updates);
}
```

(In your screenshot **items** is equal to **firebase-test**)

[Here the Firebase Realtime Database documentation.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write)

Comment: i tried it out and I can still see the item in my database

Comment: yeah, did that.

Comment: Are you sure that the key really exist ?

Comment: Okay I think a know why, You may have forgotten the '-' char (the first char of your key)

Comment: Yes, it did work. Yay!!
thanks.
could you also tell me what to do if I just want to remove just the title or the user?

Comment: return firebase.database().ref('items').child('ITEM_KEY').child('title').remove(); and to remove a user https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#delete_a_user

Comment: thank you so much. all this isnt mentioned at all in the docs. I tried to read the docs but couldnt understand then. Now, It's pretty clear to me. Thanks to you.